# Stirling Number of the Second Kind Identity

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'm aware of the identity
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{k} i! \binom{n+1}{i + 1} S(k,i) = H_{n,-k},
\end{align}
where $H_{n,-k}$ is a generalized Harmonic number defined by $H_{n,m} = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} r^{-m}$. I believe the following sum is related to the generalized Harmonic numbers as well,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{k} (-1)^{i} i! \binom{n-i}{k-i} S(j,i)
\end{align}
and should be a nice function of $n, k$ and $j$, where $0 \leq j, k \leq n$. Any hints are certainly welcome!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that you're going to be able to get a nice expression in general (although I would be happy to be proved wrong!).

The special case $j = n$ has a very simple expression in terms of the [Eulerian numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number), though.  We have
$$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i i! \binom{n-i}{k-i} \left\{ n \atop i\right\} = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i i! \binom{n-i}{n-k} \left\{ n \atop i\right\} = (-1)^k \left\langle n \atop n-k\right\rangle,$$
where the first step follows from $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$ and the second step from a known expression for the Eulerian numbers (see Eq. 6.40, *Concrete Mathematics*, 2nd edition, p. 269).  The Eulerian number $\left\langle n \atop k\right\rangle$ counts the number of permutations on $n$ elements in which exactly $k$ are larger than the immediately preceding element.

Maybe the case $j = 2$ is of interest as well.  Here we have $$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i i! \binom{n-i}{k-i} \left\{ 2 \atop i\right\} = 2\binom{n-2}{k-2} -\binom{n-1}{k-1} = 2\binom{n-2}{k-2} -\left[\binom{n-2}{k-1} + \binom{n-2}{k-2}\right] $$
$$= \binom{n-2}{k-2} -\binom{n-2}{k-1},$$
which is the just the triangle you get when you take differences of neighboring entries in Pascal's triangle.  This triangle can also be thought of as two copies of [Catalan's triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansTriangle.html), one positive and one negative, although the numbers are shifted and rotated.

Answer (score 3):

By way  of enrichment  of this discussion  we give a  purely algebraic
proof that does not use Eulerian numbers.

Suppose we seek to prove that
$$\sum_{q=0}^n q! {m+1\choose q+1} {n\brace q} = H_{m,-n}$$
with $m\ge n.$

Recall  the bivariate generating  function $G(z,  u)$ of  the Stirling
numbers of the second kind which is
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

This yields for the sum that
$$\sum_{q=0}^n q! {m+1\choose q+1} n! [z^n] [u^q] \exp(u(\exp(z)-1))
\\= n! [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^n q! {m+1\choose q+1} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!}
= n! [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^n {m+1\choose q+1} (\exp(z)-1)^q.$$

An important observation at this point is that $\exp(z)-1$ starts at
$z$, so  we may  extend the summation  to $m$ without  affecting the
coefficient of $z^n,$ getting
$$n! [z^n] \sum_{q=0}^m {m+1\choose q+1} (\exp(z)-1)^q.$$
Rewrite this as
$$(m+1) \times n! [z^n] 
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q+1}
\\= (m+1) \times n! [z^n] \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}
\sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{q+1}}{q+1}.$$

Stop for a moment to perform a formal power series integration.
We have $$(1+x)^m = \sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} x^q$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{m+1}(1+x)^{m+1} - \frac{1}{m+1}
=\frac{1}{m+1}\left((1+x)^{m+1} - 1\right)
\\= \sum_{q=0}^m {m\choose q} \frac{x^{q+1}}{q+1}.$$

Apply this to the sum to obtain
$$(m+1) \times n! [z^n] \frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}
\frac{1}{m+1}\left(\exp(z(m+1)) - 1\right)$$
which is
$$n! [z^n] \frac{\exp(z(m+1)) - 1}{\exp(z)-1}
= n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^m \exp(zk)
\\= n! \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{k^n}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^m k^n = H_{m, -n}.$$